# Looking for a working example to add srt subtitles to video in xcode

Tags: xcode4.3

Any one please help me… my app is based on showing subtitles under video…I did little bit in that by using Movie Player project from developer.apple, I can play and pause the subtitle while play and pause the video. I have a problem with how to synchronize the video with subtitle such as forward, backward, slider,entering full screen. I looking for an example like synchronize .srt file with MPMoviePlayerController in Xcode and also other..Please discuss your idea in that with me... Thank you